# Amazon RDS MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am struggling to setup replica with Amazon RDS. I want to make RDS as my master but for slave I want to setup my server outside of RDS. For now I am setting my slave at EC2. I have checked AWS doc for the information but could not find the exact answer to my question.

However I did found a blog post which have POC for doing it http://www.ruempler.eu/2013/07/07/replicating-aws-rds-mysql-databases-to-external-slaves/

But the problem that I facing is I am getting error

ERROR: Got error reading packet from server: Slave can not handle replication events with the checksum that master is configured to log

I tried to set binlog_checksum = none at RDS but RDS is not letting me change its config file.

Please suggest me folks!!

Comment: just a suggestion: move your slaves in RDS and follow the instructions there, or move your master to an EC2. Use one ecosystem for masters and slaves.

Comment: What version of MySQL Server is *your* server, the slave?

Comment: @Sam I cannot move my master to EC2 because my goal is to migrate from RDS to our local sever.

Comment: @Michael I am using 5.6 both on my master as well as slave.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS DMS (Data migration service) for this purpose. It will support replication between any 2 MySQL DBs.

Please refer our blog:
https://medium.com/tensult/cross-account-and-cross-region-rds-mysql-db-replication-part-1-55d307c7ae65

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, but I bumped into it while searching for similar functionality. Amazon supports both replication from an external master and replicating to an external slave these days:

**Replication from external master:**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.External.Repl.html

**Replication to external slave:**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Exporting.NonRDSRepl.html

Hope this helps future searchers.

Comment: See answer below @walter-heck, I don't believe this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be possible as of now (December, 2017).

Looking at @walter-heck's second link above, it is actually (another) explanation of "... replication between an external master instance and a DB instance on Amazon RDS".

It does not appear you can setup an external replica which connects to a RDS running as master.

AWS does offer this service, of course, however each replica must be within RDS.

With all the service offerings AWS has, one would think this would be possible. However, it may not work well with the AWS business model, because you don't pay based on external replicas - you pay based on RDS size.